# Why is my jQuery resize firing inconsistently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-scrollify

I'm wrapping up a site that involves a few elements (image / text / diagonal line) that have to scale proportionately on different screens.

Because there's text that has to be resized, I'm using jQuery to calculate the measurements for all of the elements based on a ratio. This was the best solution I could think of at the time, and with a deadline approaching, I think I'm stuck with it. It's a single-page site that scrolls by the page (e.g., full pages in the viewport).

[Here's a link to the demo site](http://bg.madebyelmcity.com)

The idea behind the code:

- We check the height of the viewport to set the container size
- Set the wrapper element height, based on the container size and necessary
  margins
- Set the width based on a ratio
- Use these values to calculate font size, image size, and offsets

As the screen is re-sized, the element shrinks proportionately to fill the available space.

It looks kind of like this:

[image: Screenshot of how it should look]

There are two panels like this. I re-use the same code (with different variable names, and a few sizing differences) for the second panel.

Here's my Javascript/jQuery for the first:

```
        // Set panel height on page load & resize   
          $(window).on("resize", function () {  
            var $panelHeight = $(window).height();
            var $headerHeight = $('.banner').height();

        // General height for panels
            $('.bg-panel').css('height', $panelHeight );
            $('.bg-panel').css('padding-top', $headerHeight);

        }).resize();

        // We want to scale content proportionately
        // First let's get some breakpoints
           var $breakPoint = 768;
           var $breakPointSM = 480;

        // Panel 1
            $(window).on("resize", function () {

        // Check height of current panel

        // If on single-column view, we want to measure the space between the text column and bottom of screen
        // Otherwise, height of entire panel

        var $windowHeight = $('.panel-test').height();  

        // But we need to subtract the header height, so our math is correct 
        var $headerHeight = $('.banner').height();
        var $windowHeight = $windowHeight - $headerHeight;

        // Now we have the correct height to work with

        // We're at 768px or below, subtract the text element from the overall height
        if ( $(document).width() <= $breakPoint) {
            var $heightofDiv = $('.panel-1-text').height();
            var $mobileHeight = $windowHeight - $heightofDiv;
            var $windowHeight = $mobileHeight;
        }

        // Save the window height for calculating our margins!
        var $windowHeightforMargins = $windowHeight;

        // Top and bottom margins
        var $marginTop = $windowHeight * (102/792); // ratio from PSD
        var $marginBottom = $windowHeight * (84/792); // ratio from PSD
        var $marginTotal = $marginTop + $marginBottom;


        // Responsive solution
        // As browser shrinks, reduce the height of panel so it produces a smaller container
        if ( $(document).width() > 1200 && $(document).width() <= 1440) {
            var $windowHeight = $windowHeight * 0.9;
            var $marginTop = $marginTop * 2;
        } 
        else if ( $(document).width() > 990 && $(document).width() <= 1200) {
            var $windowHeight = $windowHeight * 0.8;
            var $marginTop = $marginTop * 3;
        } 
        else if ( $(document).width() > $breakPoint && $(document).width() <= 990) {
            var $windowHeight = $windowHeight * 0.7;
            var $marginTop = $marginTop * 3.5;
        } 
        else if ( $(document).width() < $breakPoint) { // Ratio here goes up again because we're accounting for new height with $mobileHeight
            var $windowHeight = $windowHeight * 0.8;
        } 

        // This ratio determines the width of the container
        var $ratio = 697 / 607; // from PSD

        // Set container height, depending on height of panel 
        if ( $(document).width() <= $breakPointSM) { 
            var $taglinesHeight = ($windowHeight * 1.5); // Scale up for phones
        } 
        else if ( $(document).width() > $breakPointSM && $(document).width() <= $breakPoint ){
            var $taglinesHeight = ($windowHeight * 1); // Scale down for tablet
        }  
        else {
            var $taglinesHeight = $windowHeight - $marginTotal;
        }

        // Set container width as ratio of height
        if ( $(document).width() <= $breakPoint) { 
            var $taglinesWidth = $taglinesHeight * $ratio
        } else {
            var $taglinesWidth = $taglinesHeight * $ratio
        }

        $('.panel-test .bg-taglines').css("width", $taglinesWidth);
        $('.panel-test .bg-taglines').css("height", $taglinesHeight);

        // Add top margin if above breakpoint
        if ( $(document).width() > $breakPoint) { // No margin unless above 768px
            $('.panel-test .bg-taglines').css("margin-top", $marginTop);
        } 
        else {
            $('.panel-test .panel-1-tagline').css("bottom", $marginTop);
        }

        // Set font size
        var $fontSize = $taglinesWidth * 0.12;
        $('.bg-panel h4').css("font-size", $fontSize);

        // Set pink line origin (relative to bottom-left of frame)
        var $pinkX = $taglinesWidth * (286 / 705);
        var $pinkY = $taglinesHeight * (192 / 607);
        $('.panel-test .animation-wrapper').css("left", $pinkX);
        $('.panel-test .animation-wrapper').css("bottom", $pinkY);

        // Set image size 
        var $imageWidth = $taglinesWidth * 0.556;
          $('.panel-test .scaleable-image').css("width", $imageWidth);

        // Set h3 margin from top
        if ( $(document).width() >= $breakPoint) { 
            var $marginH3 = $windowHeight * (217/792); // ratio from PSD
            $('.panel-test h3').css("margin-top", $marginH3);
        } else { 
            // CSS
        }   

        // Set line offset from top
        var $lineOffset = $taglinesHeight * 0.7;
            $('.panel-test .line-wrapper').css("top", $lineOffset);

        // Set line length
        var $lineLong = $taglinesWidth * 1;
            $('.panel-test .pink-line').css("width", $lineLong);

}).resize();
```

It works: **MOST** of the time.

If I drag my window to resize, some of the elements get resized. Others don't.

A page refresh generally solves it, but right now, elements (mostly the images!) just aren't scaling properly and in sync with other elements.

I'm very new to jQuery and this is my first big undertaking. New to using  `resize` as well. Hoping I just made a goof that's easy to fix.

Thanks!

[LIVE SITE LINK](http://bg.madebyelmcity.com)

Other plugins in use: [jQuery Scrollify](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify/) (for full page scrolling) and [ScrollReveal](https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal.js).

Answer (score 0):

Guess I can answer my own question.

The issue seemed to be that the values were getting mixed up when scrolling from one full-screen panel to another.

Changing this:

`$(window).on("resize", function () {`

To this:

`$(window).on("resize load scroll", function (e) {`

... solved the issue. I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it, but the resizes are all working fine now.